# How to make a picturebox hide when dragged over another picturebox?

Tags: vb.net-2010

So I nailed the ability to drag a picturebox around the Windows form. I need it to hide itself when it's dragged and dropped over another picture. I've tried a few methods but none seem to work and I am now back at square one, the only code I have is so that I can move the picturebox around the form.

Comment: Can you describe (or even copy explicitly the code of) what you have tried?

Comment: Ok scratch that, the code was completly irreverent to what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved Your Problem

Here Is How The Form Should Look Like

[image]

And Here Is The Code I Made:

```
    Private Sub CheckTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckTimer.Tick
    CheckTimer.Stop()
    CheckTimer.Interval = 1
    If PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) Then
        PictureBox2.Visible = False
    End If
    CheckTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = PictureBox1.Location.X
    TextBox2.Text = PictureBox1.Location.Y
    CheckTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

Hope This Code Was Helpful To You.

Answer (score 0):

I made an better code than the old one,  try it.

Here Is How The Form Should Look Like:

[image]

and here is the code :

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Point As New Point
Dim X, Y As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Interval = 1
    Point = Cursor.Position
    PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Point.X - X, Point.Y - Y)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown
    X = Cursor.Position.X - PictureBox2.Location.X
    Y = Cursor.Position.Y - PictureBox2.Location.Y
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseUp
    Timer1.Stop()
    If PictureBox2.Location.X < PictureBox1.Size.Width Then
        PictureBox2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

I hope this code was useful to you.